# Implementing a multiple input filter graph with the Libavfilter library in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the `overlay` filter with multiple input sources, for an Android app. Basically, I want to overlay multiple video sources on top of a static image.
I have looked at the sample that comes with ffmpeg and implemented my code based on that, but things don't seem to be working as expected.

In the ffmpeg filtering sample there seems to be a single video input. I have to handle multiple video inputs and I am not sure that my solution is the correct one. I have tried to find other examples, but looks like this is the only one.

Here is my code:

```c
AVFilterContext **inputContexts;
AVFilterContext *outputContext;
AVFilterGraph *graph;

int initFilters(AVFrame *bgFrame, int inputCount, AVCodecContext **codecContexts, char *filters)
{
    int i;
    int returnCode;
    char args[512];
    char name[9];
    AVFilterInOut **graphInputs = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *graphOutput = NULL;

    AVFilter *bufferSrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    AVFilter *bufferSink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");

    graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if(graph == NULL)
        return -1;

    //allocate inputs
    graphInputs = av_calloc(inputCount + 1, sizeof(AVFilterInOut *));
    for(i = 0; i <= inputCount; i++)
    {
        graphInputs[i] = avfilter_inout_alloc();
        if(graphInputs[i] == NULL)
            return -1;
    }

    //allocate input contexts
    inputContexts = av_calloc(inputCount + 1, sizeof(AVFilterContext *));
    //first is the background
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=1/1:pixel_aspect=0", bgFrame->width, bgFrame->height, bgFrame->format);
    returnCode = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&inputContexts[0], bufferSrc, "background", args, NULL, graph);
    if(returnCode < 0)
        return returnCode;
    graphInputs[0]->filter_ctx = inputContexts[0];
    graphInputs[0]->name = av_strdup("background");
    graphInputs[0]->next = graphInputs[1];

    //allocate the rest
    for(i = 1; i <= inputCount; i++)
    {
        AVCodecContext *codecCtx = codecContexts[i - 1];
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
                    codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,
                    codecCtx->time_base.num, codecCtx->time_base.den,
                    codecCtx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, codecCtx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "video_%d", i);

        returnCode = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&inputContexts[i], bufferSrc, name, args, NULL, graph);
        if(returnCode < 0)
            return returnCode;

        graphInputs[i]->filter_ctx = inputContexts[i];
        graphInputs[i]->name = av_strdup(name);
        graphInputs[i]->pad_idx = 0;
        if(i < inputCount)
        {
            graphInputs[i]->next = graphInputs[i + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            graphInputs[i]->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    //allocate outputs
    graphOutput = avfilter_inout_alloc();   
    returnCode = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&outputContext, bufferSink, "out", NULL, NULL, graph);
    if(returnCode < 0)
        return returnCode;
    graphOutput->filter_ctx = outputContext;
    graphOutput->name = av_strdup("out");
    graphOutput->next = NULL;
    graphOutput->pad_idx = 0;

    returnCode = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(graph, filters, graphInputs, &graphOutput, NULL);
    if(returnCode < 0)
        return returnCode;

    returnCode = avfilter_graph_config(graph, NULL);
        return returnCode;

    return 0;
}
```

The `filters` argument of the function is passed on to `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` and it can looks like this: `[background] scale=512x512 [base]; [video_1] scale=256x256 [tmp_1]; [base][tmp_1] overlay=0:0 [out]`

The call breaks after the call to `avfilter_graph_config` with the warning:
`Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "background" of buffer not connected to any destination` and the error `Invalid argument`.

What is it that I am not doing correctly?

EDIT: The are two issues that I have discovered:

1. Looks like the description of `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` is a bit vague. The `ouputs` parameter represents a list of the current outputs of the graph, in my case that being the `graphInputs` variable, because these are the outputs from the `buffer` filter. The `inputs` parameter represents a list of the current inputs of the graph, in this case this is the `graphOutput` variable, because it represents the input to the `buffersink` filter.
2. I did some testing with a `scale` filter and a single input. It seems that the name of the `AVFilterInOut` structure required by `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` needs to be `in`. I have tried with different versions: `in_1`, `in_link_1`. None of them work and I have not been able to find any documentation related to this.

So the issue still remains. How do I implement a filter graph with multiple inputs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found a simple solution to the problem.
This involves replacing the `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` with `avfilter_graph_parse2` and adding the `buffer` and `buffersink` filters to the `filters` parameter of `avfilter_graph_parse2`.

So, in the simple case where you have one background image and one input video the value of the `filters` parameter should look like this:

`buffer=video_size=1024x768:pix_fmt=2:time_base=1/25:pixel_aspect=3937/3937 [in_1]; buffer=video_size=1920x1080:pix_fmt=0:time_base=1/180000:pixel_aspect=0/1 [in_2]; [in_1] [in_2] overlay=0:0 [result]; [result] buffersink`

The `avfilter_graph_parse2` will make all the graph connections and initialize all the filters. The filter contexts for the input buffers and for the output buffer can be retrieved from the graph itself at the end. These are used to add/get frames from the filter graph.

A simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
AVFilterContext **inputContexts;
AVFilterContext *outputContext;
AVFilterGraph *graph;

int initFilters(AVFrame *bgFrame, int inputCount, AVCodecContext **codecContexts)
{
    int i;
    int returnCode;
    char filters[1024];
    AVFilterInOut *gis = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *gos = NULL;

    graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if(graph == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate filter graph.");        
        return -1;
    }

    //build the filters string here
    // ...

    returnCode = avfilter_graph_parse2(graph, filters, &gis, &gos);
    if(returnCode < 0)
    {
        cs_printAVError("Cannot parse graph.", returnCode);
        return returnCode;
    }

    returnCode = avfilter_graph_config(graph, NULL);
    if(returnCode < 0)
    {
        cs_printAVError("Cannot configure graph.", returnCode);
        return returnCode;
    }

    //get the filter contexts from the graph here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, I'm trying to overlay a video (with an alpha channel) on top of a JPG, I can easily do this on the command line but I'm having a really hard time putting it all together in code. Could you please share the code ? Thank you so much

Comment: Could you also add how you receive the contexts from the graph with avfilter_graph_get_filter? I can't really figure out what name automatically created filters would have. Or is there a different way to receive the contexts to use them? I'm talking about your "//get the filter contexts from the graph here" comment.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP , when executing `avfilter_graph_parse2(...); avfilter_graph_config(graph, NULL)`, you'll see the filters form a linked list. `in_1` and `in_2` filter context can be got by `avfilter_graph_get_filter(graph, "Parsed_buffer_0"); ` and `avfilter_graph_get_filter(graph, "Parsed_buffer_1")`. You should better debug the  program and check the graph's  `filters` field, it's the linked list constructed from the parsed string.

Comment: you can also name your filters, for example: `buffer@buffer_input=...` - in this case you will find this name in the filter graph

Answer (score 1):

I cant add a comment so i would just like to add you can fix "Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "background" of buffer not connected to any destination" by not having a sink at all. The filter will automatically make the sink for you.  So you are adding too many pads

Comment: Yes, that is what I eventually ended up doing.

Comment: Hi guys, from where you got documentation to use FFMPEG 'C' api especially for filters. I want to use overlay filter and want to create a video from image, but I am unable to find any kind of documentation or examples about using 'C' api. Struggling on it since last 15 days, but all struggles were fruit less. There is much information about doing this via command but I want to do this via 'C API'. PLEASE GUIDE ME !!!

Answer (score 1):

For my case I had a transformation like this:

```
[0:v]pad=1008:734:144:0:black[pad];[pad][1:v]overlay=0:576[out]
```

If you try ffmpeg from command line, it will work:

```
ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -i second.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=1008:734:144:0:black[pad];[pad][1:v]overlay=0:576[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Basically, increasing the overall size of first video, then overlapping the second one. After a long try, same problems as this thread, I got it working. The video filtering example from FFMPEG documentation (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2filtering_video_8c-example.html) works fine, and after digging into it, this went fine:

```
    filterGraph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    NULLC(filterGraph);

    bufferSink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    NULLC(bufferSink);
    filterInput = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVBufferSinkParams* buffersinkParams = av_buffersink_params_alloc();
    buffersinkParams->pixel_fmts = pixelFormats;

    FFMPEGHRC(avfilter_graph_create_filter(&bufferSinkContext, bufferSink, "out", NULL, buffersinkParams, filterGraph));

    av_free(buffersinkParams);

    filterInput->name = av_strdup("out");
    filterInput->filter_ctx = bufferSinkContext;
    filterInput->pad_idx = 0;
    filterInput->next = NULL;

    filterOutputs = new AVFilterInOut*[inputFiles.size()];
    ZeroMemory(filterOutputs, sizeof(AVFilterInOut*) * inputFiles.size());
    bufferSourceContext = new AVFilterContext*[inputFiles.size()];
    ZeroMemory(bufferSourceContext, sizeof(AVFilterContext*) * inputFiles.size());

    for (i = inputFiles.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d", 
            videoCodecContext[i]->width, videoCodecContext[i]->height, videoCodecContext[i]->pix_fmt, videoCodecContext[i]->time_base.num, videoCodecContext[i]->time_base.den, videoCodecContext[i]->sample_aspect_ratio.num, videoCodecContext[i]->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

        filterOutputs[i] = avfilter_inout_alloc();
        NULLC(filterOutputs[i]);
        bufferSource = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        NULLC(bufferSource);
        sprintf(args2, outputTemplate, i);
        FFMPEGHRC(avfilter_graph_create_filter(&bufferSourceContext[i], bufferSource, "in", args, NULL, filterGraph));

        filterOutputs[i]->name = av_strdup(args2);
        filterOutputs[i]->filter_ctx = bufferSourceContext[i];
        filterOutputs[i]->pad_idx = 0;
        filterOutputs[i]->next = i < inputFiles.size() - 1 ? filterOutputs[i + 1] : NULL;
    }

    FFMPEGHRC(avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filterGraph, description, &filterInput, filterOutputs, NULL));
    FFMPEGHRC(avfilter_graph_config(filterGraph, NULL));
```

The type of variables are the same as in example above, the args and args2 are char[512], where outputTemplate is "%d:v", basically the input video IDs from filtering expression. Couple of things to watch-out:

- The video information in args, needs to be correct, time_base and sample_aspect_ration are copied from the video stream of format context.
- Indeed the input, is what is for us output, and the other way around
- The name of the filter is "in" for all our input filters(filterOutputs)